# My code gives out Environment variables on Linux

Tags: c, path, environment-variables, stdout, stdio

Some of this code might not make any sense, (perhaps even I am perplexed) about how  this happened and why? 
This code was intended for some other purpose, (i was trying to make a calculator, so the main source code [which had few problems] exists on this site as my question) i somehow broke it and so i modified it and extracted the code which initially broke it.

I tested it on Kali Linux.

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Some of this might not make any sense, but its the way i was able to break it.. somehow
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[2],"a");
    if(file == NULL) {
        printf("Error Opening File!");
        return 1;
    }
    char ch;
    int i;
    printf("%i\n",argc);
    printf("%i\n",argv);
    while((ch = getopt(argc,argv,"d:"))!=EOF)
        switch(ch) {
        case 'd':
            for(i=4; i<=48; i++) // This loop may vary on other system. On first run i used "i<=51" , and on different system, same os, its the mentioned condition
                fprintf(file,"%s \n",argv[i]);
            fclose(file);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr,"No such command");
        }
    argc-=1;
    argv+=1;


    return 0;
}
```

The following result was produced upon running (the original source code. This code will write it to a file) :

> value at argv=
>   LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
>
> value at argv= XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
>
> value at argv= LANG=en_IN
>
> value at argv= GDM_LANG=en_IN
>
> value at argv= MANAGERPID=793
>
> value at argv= DISPLAY=:1
>
> value at argv= INVOCATION_ID=3e7f771adfde4001af637f9527e9cc9d
>
> value at argv= COLORTERM=truecolor
>
> value at argv= USERNAME=root
>
> value at argv= XDG_VTNR=2
>
> value at argv= SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/0/keyring/ssh
>
> value at argv= S_COLORS=auto
>
> value at argv= XDG_SESSION_ID=3
>
> value at argv= USER=root
>
> value at argv= DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
>
> value at argv= PWD=/media/root/F89AF7139AF6CCDE
>
> value at argv= HOME=/root
>
> value at argv= JOURNAL_STREAM=9:19456
>
> value at argv= SSH_AGENT_PID=945
>
> value at argv= QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
>
> value at argv= XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
>
> value at argv=
>   XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
>
> value at argv= XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome
>
> value at argv=
>   DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus,guid=11c587e1337f9fb06858c2415bbac73a
>
> value at argv= GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
>
> value at argv= WINDOWPATH=2
>
> value at argv= TERM=xterm-256color
>
> value at argv= SHELL=/bin/bash
>
> value at argv= VTE_VERSION=5002
>
> value at argv= DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE=session
>
> value at argv= XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
>
> value at argv= GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
>
> value at argv= SHLVL=1
>
> value at argv= XDG_SEAT=seat0
>
> value at argv= LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
>
> value at argv= WINDOWID=39845894
>
> value at argv= GDMSESSION=gnome
>
> value at argv= GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
>
> value at argv= LOGNAME=root
>
> value at argv=
>   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus,guid=11c587e1337f9fb06858c2415bbac73a
>
> value at argv= XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
>
> value at argv= XAUTHORITY=/run/user/0/gdm/Xauthority
>
> value at argv=
>   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
>
> value at argv=
>   SESSION_MANAGER=local/kali:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/894,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/894
>
> value at argv= _=./a.out
>
> value at argv= (null)

My question that follows is, what actually are environment variables? And why did my give me such results?

```
// probably use one option at a time
//This code has some flaws, for example i didnt check if the file was opened 
or not, etc, pardon me for it. This is the actual un-edited source of the 
code.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int add(int a,int b){
return a+b;
}

int subtract(int a, int b){
return a-b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
FILE *file1 = fopen("Results.txt","a");
char ch;
int res;
while((ch=getopt(argc,argv,"a:s:"))!=EOF)
    switch (ch){
        case 'a':
            res = add(atoi(optarg),atoi(argv[3]));
            fprintf(file1,"%i\n",res);
            break;
        case 's':
            res = subtract(atoi(optarg),atoi(argv[3]));
            printf("%i \n",res);
            fprintf(file1,"%i\n",res);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr,"No such option");
            return 1;

    }
//THe commented out section produces weird behaviour...

//printf("Opind = %i, argc = %i, argv = %i \n",optind,argc,argv);

argc-=optind;

//printf("value at optarg = %i value at argv_3= %s \n",optarg,argv[3]);

argv+=optind;

//printf("Opind = %i, argc = %i, argv = %i \n",optind,argc,argv);

//printf("value at optarg = %i value at argv_3= %s \n",optarg,argv[1]);

fprintf(file1,"\nWritten to file\n");

fclose(file1);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: It really isn't clear what your actual question is here

Comment: My apologies, somehow my question part got skipped, pardon me i will edit the question

Comment: This code won’t produce such output. If some other code does, how does it relate to this code? And if the question is “what are environment variables” how does that relate to the code? That question is easily answered with your favorite search engine.

Comment: So, the results may vary on various Operating Systems?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I will re-edit and include the original source sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, going out of bounds of an array leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You probably do that when you iterate over the `argv` array without checking for e.g. `i < argc` (unless you actually provide over 48 arguments on the command line).

Secondly, as for why you print the environment variables when going out of bounds of `argv`, it's because on POSIX systems (like Linux or macOS) there's a *third* argument to the `main` function, usually called `environ`. Similar to `argv` it's an array of strings (declared the same way, e.g. `char *environ[]`) that contains the environment variables. By going out of bounds of `argv` you go into the memory for the `environ` array.

---

On a related note, you use `argv[2]` without any checking that the argument actually exists, or that it's not any other argument you parse with `getopt`. Don't do that.

Also note that the [`getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) function returns an *`int`*. This is actually very significant and important for the check against `-1` (not `EOF`!).

Comment: That helped me understand it, about the EOF part, i wrote it since i learned it from a book, i guess it must be a misprint there, the book i referred to was HFC (Head First C)